# Calling initialization function inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I am trying to call `ng-init` function inside `ng-repeat` and it only works only on the first element:

```
<li ng-repeat="comment in ad.comments|limitTo:quantity | orderBy : sortComment : true">
        <div id="starsDiv" ng-init="orderComment(comment.stars)"></div>
          Comment: {{comment.text}}
          <cite class="clearfix">  on {{comment.posted | date}}</cite>
</li>
```

The `orderComment` inside `ng-repeat` function needs to init the `starDiv`:

```
$scope.orderComment= function(numOfStars){
                   var html = '<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;"></i>';
                    for(var i =0 ; i<numOfStars-1;i++)
                    {
                        html += '<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;"></i>';
                    }
                    document.getElementById("starsDiv").innerHTML = html;
                };
```

Injecting HTML to the `starsDiv` by the value of `comment.stars`.
For instance if comment equals 4 there will be 4 HTML elements of :

```
'<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;"></i>'
```

inside it.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/330kedvq/

Comment: I'm injecting HTML inside ng-init .

Comment: You shouldn't do that with `ng-init`. Either put the html in the div or use a custom directive that will take `comment.stars` and render it.

Comment: Can you create a 'jsfiddle' for that?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/330kedvq/1/

Comment: Is there any chance for the first option: "put the html in the div"? the second one doesn't match because I 'stars' is a number that by its value I need to create : ' <i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;"></i>'

Comment: Edit the question and explain exactly what you're trying to do. Otherwise I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Angular discourages making changes in the DOM on your own, and in this case it's not necessary.

A simple solution might be to put in the maximum amount of possible stars and using `ng-show` to show only the amount we need. Assuming there are 5 stars:

```
<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;" ng-show="comment.stars > 0"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;" ng-show="comment.stars > 1"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;" ng-show="comment.stars > 2"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;" ng-show="comment.stars > 3"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;" ng-show="comment.stars > 4"></i>
```

If you need a general solution, you can always use `ng-repeat`. You simply need a function that will take a number and return an array of that size. You can use the array like this.

```
<i class="fa fa-star-o" style="color:gold;" ng-repeat="x in array(comment.stars)"></i>
```

An even more general solution would be to create a custom directive that renders these stars. I recommend reading about custom directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: All your solutions works great, I think that the custom directive is the right way to do it.